# How to check if a user inputted string meets requirements

Tags: python

I'm extremely new to coding/python and I need to check if the user of the program is a member of an organization. This is part of a bigger program but this is what I have so far:

```
member = str(input("Enter your membership status, y or n: "))
elif member == y:
    print ("You are a member")
elif member == n:
    print("You need a membership")
```

How do I just check if the user is a member and not print anything and if they're not a member print that they need a membership?

Comment: If you don't want to print anything for members, then don't check for `"y"` input.  Only check for `"n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
member = str(input("Enter your membership status, y or n: "))
if member == 'y':
    print ("You are a member")
elif member == 'n':
    print("You need a membership")
```

1. since your `member` variable is having string content, you need to put the values of string in quotes in your if condition `member == 'y'`.
2. when checking the condition, first you need to start with if instead of elif.

Comment: `input()` already returns a string.  You don't need to put `str(   )` around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lower()` method of string so as to eliminate the possibility of case mismatching, like this...

```py
member = input("Enter your membership status, y or n: ")
if member.lower() == 'y':
    print ("You are a member")
elif member.lower() == 'n':
    print("You need a membership")
else:
    print("Invalid Option")
```

Now it will work even for the block letters of `y` and `n`